# Angular $http post() format Defaults to HTML on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, http

I have a factory that exposes a create() function which uses $http.post() underneath.  For some reason when it is called from an ng-click the request is being formatted as HTML. All of the params are where I want them to be, but Rails is processing the request as HTML.

The factory:

```
orizabaServices.factory('requestTypeFactory', ["$http", function($http){
    var urlBase = '/request_types';
    var requestTypeFactory = {};

    requestTypeFactory.create = function(params){
      data = {};
      data.authenticity_token =  $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
      data.request_type = params;
      return $http.post(urlBase, data)
    };

    return requestTypeFactory;
  }
])
```

The Error:

```
Started POST "/request_types" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-01 17:10:00 +0000
Processing by RequestTypesController#create as HTML
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the format of the request adding '.json' to your urlBase. For example:

```
var urlBase = '/request_types.json';
```

Comment: I understood that the post() was supposed to set a default JSON format, so I see this as kind of a workaround.  I can't blame rails because it handles the request fine when it is formatted correctly.  But this is a simple and reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "full URL" for urlBase. If you request POST method on your local machine

```
var urlBase = 'http://127.0.0.1/request_types';
```

try this

Comment: Passing the full URL doesn't affect.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

It's because by default rails is considerng all requests as HTML. You can change this behaviour in your config/routes.rb file like this:

```
resources :request_types, :defaults => {:format => 'json'}
```